# Big Query give user access to a single table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-iam

I wanted to give a user the ability to view and query a single table in a much larger dataset. Is there some way to allow the user to query just that table? I know I can restrict access to datasets, but is there a way to give permissions at a table level?

Comment: you can mark my answer as the accepted answer now since it solves your original question https://stackoverflow.com/a/73937576/391034

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving access on a per-table basis is possible in GCP now. Check https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls-intro for more details, but essentially, you need to use the `bigquery.tables.setIamPolicy` directive to grant access to specific tables.

So, for example, using the `bq` CLI command, you can run the following command to grant access to table `xyz`

```
bq set-iam-policy --table=true xyz
```

Answer (score 7):

Table ACL has been introduced in beta, see doc here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls-intro

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to set permission on table level! As you mentioned in your question  - you can so this only on dataset level

Meantime, there is workaround that might help you - you can use so called [`authorized view`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views)

what you can do is create new dataset (let's say for such users) and inside that dataset you create view on top of table of interest. Now you can give that view VIEW permission for original dataset using authorized view option. SO in this case you don't need to give the user VIEW permission to original dataset. The only what user need is VIEW permission to dataset where this new view is created

Comment: I think this works for me in this case, but for large partitioned tables it [looks like querying specific partitions will not reduce cost.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro) Is that the case?

Comment: of course, any [view limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro#view_limitations) will apply here :o(

Comment: I believe permissions on table and view level are now supported:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, there's not way of sharing single table. Creating an Authorized View is the way to go, see full tutorial here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views